# Excel report Formatting in PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

Need help to create a script to get a HPOA server blade Health report
The problem is that when I get query Health it outputs in a PSO object with fields (IP,Health,Blades(@{Blade1 Health}{Blade2 Health}{3} . . .) ) 
I want a report like below

IP           Bay Power        Health
--            --- -----       -----
10.3.131.2    1 On              OK
              2 On              OK
              3 On              OK
              4 On              OK
              5 On            Degraded

The variables are derived as below .

$sstaInfo = {} | Select IP, Bay, Power, Health, DeviceFailure
$sstaInfo.IP=$ssta.IP (Gives a single IP output)
$sstaInfo.Bay=$sstaBlades.Bay                       $sstaInfo.Power=$sstaBlades.Power
$sstaInfo.Health=$sstaBlades.Health

How can I get this working ?

$ssta variable has the below output : 
@{Power=On; CurrentWattageUsed=480; Health=OK; UnitIdentificationLED=Off; VirtualFan=33%; DiagnosticStatus=; Bay=1} @{Power=On; CurrentWattageUsed=576; Health=OK; UnitIdentificationLED=Off; VirtualFan=47%; DiagnosticStatus=; Bay=2}

```
#------------------------------------------------------------  Input    Variable Definations

$HPOAServers =@(
[pscustomobject]@{Name='10.11.12.13'},
[pscustomobject]@{Name='10.11.12.14'}
)

$Username ="admin"
$Password ="admin"

#------------------------------------------------------------  Main Script Starts Here

# Function for connecting to OA and returning connection object on success




foreach ($HPOAServer in $HPOAServers) {

$con = Connect-HPOA $HPOAServer.Name -username $Username -password $Password

$report = @()

$ssta = Get-HPOAServerStatus -Bay All $con  

                $sstaBlade=$ssta.Blade
                Write-Host $sstaBlade
                Foreach ($sstaBlades in $sstaBlade) {
                    $i++

                    $sstaInfo = {} | Select IP, Bay, Power, Health, DeviceFailure                  
                    $sstaInfo.IP=$ssta.IP
                    $sstaInfo.Bay=$sstaBlades.Bay
                    $sstaInfo.Power=$sstaBlades.Power
                    $sstaInfo.Health=$sstaBlades.Health
$sstaInfo.DeviceFailure=$ssta.Blade.DiagnosticStatus.DeviceFailure


                }




$report += $ssta | Select-Object -Property IP
$report += $ssta.Blade | Select-Object -Property Bay, Power, Health | Format-Table *                        
$report | out-file "HPOA_Health_Report.txt" -Append         

}
Disconnect-HPOA $con
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function HPOA () {
try
{
        Remove-Item -Path $outputfile -Force
        foreach ($HPOAServer in $HPOAServers) 
        {
            $con = Connect-HPOA $HPOAServer.Name -username $Username -password $Password -ErrorAction 'Stop'
            $ssta = Get-HPOAServerStatus -Bay All $con

        $ssta.Blade | Foreach-Object { 
        $sstaInfo = $_

        $sstaInfo | Select-Object -Property @{Name="Chassis_IP_Address";Expression={$ssta.IP}},
            @{Name="Blade_Power_Status";Expression={$_.Power}},
            @{Name="Blade_Bay_Number";Expression={$_.Bay}},
            @{Name="Blade_Health_Status";Expression={$_.Health}},
            @{Name="Blade_Diagnostic_DeviceFailure_Status";Expression={$ssta.Blade.DiagnosticStatus.DeviceFailure}}

        } | ConvertTo-Html -Title " $HPOARegionName HPOA Health Report " -Head $Header -Body "<H2> $HPOARegionName HPOA Health Report </H2>" -As Table | Out-File -Append $outputfile 
        Disconnect-HPOA $con
    }


}

catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    Write-Host $ErrorMessage
    Write-Host $FailedItem

}

}

HPOA
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Export-CSV instead, so below line

```
 $report | Out-File "HPOA_Health_Report.txt" -Append
```

will be replaced by:

```
 $report | Export-Csv "HPOA_Health_Report.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```